# np.random.choice() isn't working as expected in an instance method

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm working on training a Reinforcement Learning agent using a Deep Q-learning Neural Network and for that, I mainly have 2 files, an environment python script and a Jupyter Notebook (using Google Colab) in which I've defined the agent class and I'm training it in there.

One of the functions in my environment Python script is `self.reset`, which, as the name implies, resets all the environment state values. This is how it looks like

```
 def reset(self):
        return self.action_space, self.state_space, self.state_space[(np.random.choice(len(self.state_space)))], self.reset_days_total(self.days_total)
```

(the `self.reset_days_total()` is simply another function from the same class, which I'm using to reset another instance variable.)

While the values of state_space and action_space remain constant throughout the entire training process, the initial state returned by the function should be randomly selected every time it is invoked.

When I try to select a random state directly on my notebook, the `np.random.choice` function works on the class variable.

```
    for i in range(5):
           print(env.state_space[(np.random.choice(len(env.state_space)))])
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 o/p: (4, 7, 0)
      (3, 2, 0)
      (4, 13, 4)
      (2, 16, 3)
      (2, 9, 5)
```

However, when I try to achieve the same using the instance method, it doesn't return a random state every time I run the method. It stops returning a random value after the first time and returns an unchanged value after that no matter how many times I run the function.

```
 env = CabDriver()
 for i in range(5):
     action_space, state_space, state_new, days_total = env.reset()
     print(f"State: {state_new}")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

o/p: State: (4, 22, 0)
     State: (4, 22, 0)
     State: (4, 22, 0)
     State: (4, 22, 0)
     State: (4, 22, 0)
```

I'm curious to know why both the cases are behaving differently and how I could overcome this peculiar behaviour while accessing the `env.reset()` method. A nudge in the right direction to get this method work as intended would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not answering the question, but `env.state_space[(np.random.choice(len(env.state_space)))]` can be simplified to `np.random.choice(env.state_space)`.

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, it can be but I need the state directly from the function, rather than the state index

Comment: That's exactly what it does. If the input is an iterable, it will select one of its elements directly.

Comment: @Reti43 np.random.choice works only for one-dimensional elements in a list, it doesn't work on a tuple with 3 elements.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that function had that restriction. `random.choice` in that case would work, but we're getting off track.